# Preserving special characters when using requests module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Anaconda Python 3.7 Jupyter Notebook with the requests module to scrape some video game data from a website.

The game "Brütal Legend" has an umlaut and appears correctly on the website I am scraping from, but when I get the data via the requests module, it shows up with the special character no longer in tact. For example, this is what I get:

**BrÃ¼tal Legend**

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import requests

targetURL = 'https://www.url.com/redacted.php?query'
r = requests.get(targetURL)
page_source = r.text
print("raw page_source", page_source)
```

What can I do to preserve the special character so that it shows up correctly in the output of my Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: For whatever reason, the server returns you UTF-8-encoded text, but claims it is Latin-1 (or requests assumes that). Try `page_source = r.content.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: @L3viathon: I tried this before `page_source = r.text.decode("utf-8")` but got an error, so I guess `r.content.decode("utf-8")` was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: `r.text` is already (incorrectly) decoded text, whereas `r.content` is bytes, which need to be decoded.

Comment: upvote for the title, exactly what I need: `special char problem in python requests response`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know charset which in Response's `Content-Type` , even though most of websites use utf8. `response.text` will use default encoding UTF8 , because it uses `decode()` and Response default encoding is None.

Note:  A number of sites didn't show charset, but they may use utf8.

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=encod#requests.Response.encoding

So why you got `BrÃ¼tal Legend` is you using wrong encoding to convert bytes into string. You should try `r.content.decode("ISO-8859-1")`

A simple example:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    utf_8 = s.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%BCtal_Legend")
    #response charset is UTF8
    print(utf_8.text[101:126])
    print(utf_8.content.decode("utf8")[101:126])

    print(utf_8.content[101:127].decode("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Output:

```
Brütal Legend - Wikipedia
Brütal Legend - Wikipedia
BrÃ¼tal Legend - Wikipedia
```

Edit:

```
print("BrÃ¼tal Legend".encode("ISO-8859-1").decode())
#Brütal Legend
```